# Loop through list from specific point?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to keep extremely large lists in the memory and then process those lists from specific points.  Since these lists will have as many as almost 400 billion numbers before processing we need to split them up but I haven't the slightest idea (since I can't find an example) of where to start when trying to process a list from a specific point in Python.  Edit: Right now we are *not trying to create multiple-dimensions* but if it's easier then I'll for sure do it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your numbers are bytes, 400GB (or 400TB if you use billion in the [long-scale meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)) does not normally fit in RAM. Therefore I guess [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) or [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the [@lazyr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953917/loop-through-list-from-specific-point/6953960#6953960) point, if you use the numpy.memmap method, then my [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681032/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-view-into-a-python-array-array/5681405#5681405) on views into numpy arrays might well be useful.

This is also the way you should be thinking if you have stacks of memory and everything *actually* is in RAM.